# adding new column with values calculated from other columns

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I was wandering how you could add a new column with values calculated from other columns.

Let's say 'small' is one that has a value less than 5. I want to record this information in a new column called 'small' where this column has value 1 if it is short and 0 otherwise.

I know you can do that with numpy like this :

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

rawData = pd.read_csv('data.csv', encoding = 'ISO-8859-1')
rawData['small'] = np.where(rawData['value'] < 5, '1', '0')
```

How would you do the same operation without using numpy?
I've read about numpy.where() but I still don't get it.

Help would be really appreciated thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert boolean mask to `integer` and then to `string`:

```
rawData['small'] = (rawData['value'] < 5).astype(int).astype(str)
```

Comment: thank you very much! is there a reason why you cast the int to string?

Comment: @SeoiMin - Because you convert it in question - `'1', '0'` are strings.

Comment: @SeoiMin - If dont need strings, simply remove `astype(str)`